# Creating a dropdown list with sub action items in asp.net, c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I need to create a dropdownlist of items. It should have an action and a sub action. for ex, how an unordered list looks.
I have to do it in my code behind only. I am getting a ListItemCollection and binding it to dropdown list.
So before i bind it to dropdown list i have to do some thing to make the the dropdown list look like the way i need.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance
Santosh

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

the solution is subclass DropDownList class and use [optgroup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/optgroup) attribute when render item.

Checkout this link:
http://ignatu.co.uk/articles/Adding_groups_to_the_ASPNET_DropDownList_control/